# Python Requests 'Session' object has no attribute 'requests'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, request, session-cookies

I am trying to scrape a page which requires login. So I need to use cookie to get access the target page. I have the cookie in json file and trying to use that along with a python requests session. But getting an error for which I got no solution after hours of research and coffee :(

Any help is greatly appreciated

Error Message:

```
In line 43, in <module>
response = BeautifulSoup(session.requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")
AttributeError: 'Session' object has no attribute 'requests'
```

My Code:

```
tempurl = ""

session = requests.Session()

def stringify(obj: dict) -> dict:
    """turn every value in the dictionary to a string"""
    for k, v in obj.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            # if value is a dictionary, stringifiy recursively
            stringify(v)
            continue
        if not isinstance(v, str):
            if isinstance(v, bool):
                # False/True -> false/true
                obj[k] = str(v).lower()
            else:
                obj[k] = str(v)
    return obj


with open('cookie.json') as f:
    cookie_list: list = json.load(f)
    # create the cookie jar from the first cookie
    cookie_jar = requests.utils.cookiejar_from_dict(stringify(cookie_list[0]))
    # append the rest of the cookies
    for cookie in cookie_list[1:]:
        requests.utils.add_dict_to_cookiejar(cookie_jar, stringify(cookie))
    session.cookies = cookie_jar


with open("asins.txt", "r", encoding = "utf-8") as a_file:
  for line in a_file:
    stripped_line = line.strip()

    asin = stripped_line
    url = tempurl.format(asin, '1')
    response = BeautifulSoup(session.requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")
    print (response)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it just be ```requests.get(url)...```?

Comment: you need only `session.get(...)` https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/

Comment: I have little knowledge about what I am doing. To be clear will that be enough to use the cookies I am trying to use?

Comment: It seems cookie is not working if I use only requests.get(...)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you used `session.requests.get` instead of `session.get`.

If you create your own `Session`, you need to use [`Session.get`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Session.get). If you prefer to use the default session, you can use `requests.get`.